# Download data from iPad in java application

Tags: java, iphone, ipad

I've tried to use `JNA` and `libimobiledevice` to access the memory of an iPad from a Java application, but I have encountered issues doing it this way.

Is there a simpler alternative?

Answer (score 2):

The simple way to make your iPad as a HTTP Server. Java application could access via HTTP Request.

You could use https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer. You just open socket for listening.